# how to deploy JSF 2.0 .WAR on ServiceMix

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, osgi, war, apache-servicemix

I need to convert my JSF 2.0 project so that it can be deployed on ServiceMix. What should be imported in the MANIFEST.MF and what should I install to the ServiceMix prior to deployment?

At first my webservice couldn't find javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet class. After I added it to Import in MANIFEST.MF, ServiceMix cannot run the installed bundle with error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle avita [157]: Unable to resolve 157.0: missing requirement [157.0] package; (package=javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)
```

How can I install package: `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` and any other package required for JSF 2.0 to work? In my web service I'm also using EclipseLink (JPA 2.0), MySQL JDBC connector, and Hibernate. It runs well on GlassFish v3.

Please advice me how should I proceed. I've searched a lot and could not find solution.

---

**Update**: I have deployed my test facelet to servicemix with further problems. In service mix I issued the following cammands to load required libraries:

```
install mvn:org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/1.2.9<br>
install mvn:org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/1.2.9<br>
install mvn:commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3<br>
install mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1<br>
install mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4<br>
install mvn:org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.digester/1.8.0<br>
install mvn:org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.discovery/0.4.0<br>
```

Now I can view simple facelets. I'm unable to load any pages with persistence via entities. I have the following error:

```
2012-08-27 11:39:11,180 | WARN  | mix-4.4.2/deploy | /avitaTest                       | ?                                   ? | 108 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.4.5.v20110725 | unavailable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:106)[157:org.apache.myfaces.core.api:1.2.9]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:137)[157:org.apache.myfaces.core.api:1.2.9]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:436)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:260)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)[108:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:765)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1215)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1273)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:873)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.4.5.v20110725]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.call(JettyServerImpl.java:158)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.call(JettyServerImpl.java:154)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.ContextClassLoaderUtils.doWithClassLoader(ContextClassLoaderUtils.java:60)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl.addServlet(JettyServerImpl.java:153)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl$Started.addServlet(ServerControllerImpl.java:266)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl.addServlet(ServerControllerImpl.java:107)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerServlet(HttpServiceStarted.java:248)[113:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerServlet(HttpServiceStarted.java:219)[113:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.registerServlet(HttpServiceProxy.java:100)[113:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.visit(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:206)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:583)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:170)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:155)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:119)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.setService(ReplaceableService.java:114)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.access$100(ReplaceableService.java:28)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService$CollectionListener.serviceAdded(ReplaceableService.java:183)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection$Tracker.addingService(ServiceCollection.java:181)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection.onStart(ServiceCollection.java:139)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.onStart(ReplaceableService.java:146)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:81)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.doPublish(WebXmlObserver.java:304)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.addingEntries(WebXmlObserver.java:153)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.register(BundleWatcher.java:186)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.access$000(BundleWatcher.java:45)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher$1.bundleChanged(BundleWatcher.java:127)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:729)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:610)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3761)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1787)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:918)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1175)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1153)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.processAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1146)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:456)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:263)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.1.10]
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I have added:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

to the `web.xml`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: OK. I'm sorry. Next time I'll update my question. You're right it wasn't an answer (only a small step to possible solution and further question).

Answer (score 0):

The underlying Pax-Web used as the HttpService, does have a hard time to get the classloaders straightened up with all those JSF stuff ... 
So actually there are quite a few Issues about JSF at Pax-Web, simple JSF applications do work
but in certain cases JSF doesn't work. 
The Pax-Web team is trying hard to get those issues out of the way. Taking a look at the provided [samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/war-jsf) of Pax-Web might give you a hint on how to get your issue fixed.